# XPath SelectNodes in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
<Document>
  <A> 
    <B> 
      <C></C>
    </B>
  </A>
  <E>
   <F>
    <C></C>
   </F>
   <G>
    <C></C>
  </G>
 </E>
</Document>
```

If i load the above XML into an XmlDocument and do a SelectSingleNode on A using the XPath query //C

```
XmlNode oNode = oDocument.SelectSingleNode("E");
XmlNodeList oNodeList = oNode.SelectNodes("//C");
```

why does it return nodes from Under B when what I would expect to happen would that it only return nodes from under E

Make sense?

Edit : How would i make it only return from that node onwards?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply: a leading // means "at any level" in the same *document* as the selected node.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath):

- //para selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus selects all para elements in the same document as the context node
- .//para selects the para element descendants of the context node

Answer (score 11):

Specifying `.//C` will achieve what you want, otherwise, the XPath starts from the document root rather than the current node.

The confusion is in the definition of `//` from the [XPath standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev) as follows:

> // is short for
>   /descendant-or-self::node()/. For
>   example, //para is short for
>   /descendant-or-self::node()/child::para
>   and so will select any para element in
>   the document (even a para element that
>   is a document element will be selected
>   by //para since the document element
>   node is a child of the root node);
>   div//para is short for
>   div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para
>   and so will select all para
>   descendants of div children.

Because `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` it starts at the document level unless you specify a node at the start.

Comment: No, the spec says "//" is "of the document root", and ".//" is of the context node. The implementation is correct.

Comment: Re the W3 Schools ref: read carefully : "in the document from the current node" - the context node is used (only) to obtain the document; then the entire document is scanned.

Comment: Yes, I updated it to reference the XPath standard and highlight where the confusion lies. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

`//C` is all C nodes in the entire document

`/E//C` would be only C nodes under E

`/C` would be only the root C node

See the [xpath syntax reference](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 3):

In the [XPATH Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#axes) you will find under 2.5 the following statement:

> //para selects all the para
>   descendants of the document root and
>   thus selects all para elements in the
>   same document as the context node

i.e. the behaviour you observe is valid. You should do something like "/E//C"

Comment: What if i didn't know how many nodes deep C was ? It could well be /E/D/G/C ?

Comment: @Gordon - "/E//C" will cope with any number of levels between the E and C.